# Can someone help figure out the error with my code?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
import java.util.*;

public class AllowedToRide

{

public static void main(String[] args)

    {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Height (cm)? ");
        double height = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Gender (male or female? ");
        String gender = keyboard.next();
        String allowed;

        if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("female"))
        {

            System.out.println("Pregnant (yes or no)? ");
            if(pregnant.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                allowed="No";
            }
                else
            {
                allowed="Yes";
            }
        }

        if(height<110)
           {
                allowed="No";
           }
           else
           {
                allowed="Yes";
           }

    }
    System.out.println("Allowed to ride (yes or no)? " + allowed);
}
```

I need to finish this for uni, and I can't figure out what the errors are when I compile it. They are pasted below:

> U:\progEnv\assignment\AllowedToRide.java:48: error: 
>   expected    System.out.println("Allowed to ride (yes or no)? " +
>   cost);
>                        ^
>
> U:\progEnv\assignment\AllowedToRide.java:48: error: illegal start of
>   type    System.out.println("Allowed to ride (yes or no)? " + cost);
>                         ^
>
> U:\progEnv\assignment\AllowedToRide.java:48: error: ')' expected
>   System.out.println("Allowed to ride (yes or no)? " + cost);
>                                                        ^
>
> U:\progEnv\assignment\AllowedToRide.java:48: error: ';' expected
>   System.out.println("Allowed to ride (yes or no)? " + cost);
>                                                          ^
>
> U:\progEnv\assignment\AllowedToRide.java:48: error: illegal start of
>   type    System.out.println("Allowed to ride (yes or no)? " + cost);
>                                                               ^
>
> U:\progEnv\assignment\AllowedToRide.java:48: error: 
>   expected    System.out.println("Allowed to ride (yes or no)? " +
>   cost);
>                                                                ^
>
> U:\progEnv\assignment\AllowedToRide.java:48: error: ';' expected
>   System.out.println("Allowed to ride (yes or no)? " + cost);
>                                                                 ^
>
> U:\progEnv\assignment\AllowedToRide.java:49: error: reached end of
>   file while parsing }  ^
>
> 8 errors

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared variable `pregnant` and your `System.out.println("Allowed to ride (yes or no)? " + cost);` is not in main method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your requirement is, the below code works fine. Hope this helps.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Height (cm)? ");
        double height = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Gender (male or female? ");
        String gender = keyboard.next();
        String allowed;

        if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("female")) {

            System.out.println("Pregnant (yes or no)? ");
            String pregnant = keyboard.next();
            if (pregnant.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                allowed = "No";
            } else {
                allowed = "Yes";
            }
        }

        if (height < 110) {
            allowed = "No";
        } else {
            allowed = "Yes";
        }

        System.out.println("Allowed to ride (yes or no)? ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. Can you please tell me what you did to fix it?

Comment: 1) `String pregnant` was not defined.
2) `print` statement was out of the main method
3) `allowed ` variable is still not defined

Comment: Oh, of course. I'm not sure how I missed declaring pregnant. Thanks again.